# How to lock text boxes?

Tags: winforms, toolbar

I am workig on winform for building up word processor using RTB, it includes some text boxes but they are reserved for special uses (Mail Merge). I dont want user to type in it, how can i avoid him, i mean is there any option for locking these text boxes to prevent user from typing in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the textbox and enable it when required...

```
textbox1.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either do:

```
textbox.Enabled = false
```

or

```
textbox.Readonly = true
```